# How do I get a single payout from Shopify using logic app?

Tags: datetime, expression, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

How can I get data for specific date, I want the schedule to get payout based on current date every day.

[image: Logic App workflow]

[image: data from Shopify]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the schedule to get payout based on current date every day.

It works for scheduling, as you have done (i.e.. Recurrence). You can set the trigger in the interval for 1 day. Here is the screenshot for your reference.
[image]

> How can i get data for specific date

For this you can use `Parse json` and Add `Filter array` connector and retrieve the data that is specified for that particular date. Here is the screenshot for your reference.

### [image]

Here is the raw output screenshot

[image]

Comment: Your solution was partly right, i used utcnow() to get the data from current date instead of using hardcode (2021-11-02), i will share my solution soon. Thank you for you response!